# C++ Map Inserting file data

Tags: c++, class, c++11, dictionary

I tried searching through the website but couldnt find the solution.

I have class declaration as below:

```
class Movie {
    // data is private by default
    string title, studio;
    short releaseYear, rank[3]; // US, non-US, world
    long long boxOffice[3];     // US, non-US, world
    enum unit {US, NON_US, WORLD};

public:
    Movie();
    Movie(string);
    string getTitle() const;
    string getStudio() const;
    int getReleaseYear() const;
    int getUSRank() const;
    int getNonUSRank() const;
    int getWorldRank() const;
    long long getUSBoxOffice() const;
    long long getNonUSBoxOffice() const;
    long long getWorldBoxOffice() const;
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream&, const Movie&);
private:
    Movie(const Movie &); // private copy constructor blocks invocation
};

class Movies {
    // data is private by default
    //static const int MAX_MOVIES = 1000;
    //Movie *movies;
    short movieCnt;
    map<string, Movie> movies;

public:
    Movies(string);
    //int getMovieCount() const;
    //const Movie* getMovie(string, int&) const;
    //const Movie * operator[](int) const;
    ~Movies();

private:
    void loadMovies(string);
    string myToLower(string) const;
    void reSize();
};

I am using this copy constuctor to insert data in the movie object in map.

Movie::Movie(string temp) {
    istringstream iS(temp);
    getline(iS, title, '\t');
    getline(iS, studio, '\t');
    iS >> releaseYear >> rank[US] >> boxOffice[US] >> rank[NON_US]
        >> boxOffice[NON_US] >> rank[WORLD] >> boxOffice[WORLD];
}

void Movies::loadMovies(string fn) {
    ifstream iS(fn);
    string s,movieTitle;
    getline(iS, s); // skip heading
    getline(iS, s);
    movieCnt=0;
    //movies = new Movie[MAX_MOVIES];
    while(!iS.eof()) {
        //movies[movieCnt++] = Movie(s);
        getline(iS, movieTitle, '\t');
        movies.insert(movieTitle,Movie(s));
        cout<<movies[movieTitle].title<<" "<<movies[movieTitle].studio;
        getline(iS, s);

    }
    iS.close();
    reSize();
}
```

I am calling the loadMovies from my main function which passes the file name as a parameter.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong in this.
I am new to map and hence I am struggling.

I was able to load data in map but I face the problem of retrieving the data.
In this program, we are asking the user to enter the movie name and then from main function we call getMovies(string) function. 
The getMovies function is as below:

```
const Movie* Movies::getMovie(string mc) const {

map<string, Movie>::const_iterator it = movies.find(mc);
//Here I want to know how to return Movie object?
```

}

Sample File Data is as below (if it helps): 
Title    Studio ReleaseYear USRank  USBoxOffice NonUSRank   NonUSBoxOffice  WorldRank   WorldBoxOffice
Avatar  Fox 2009    1   760507625   1   2021800000  1   2782300000

Comment: You can compile and run, but behavior is not as expected? What happens?

Comment: To insert elements in a `map` u need to make a `pair`, then u can use
`movies.insert(std::pair<std::string, Movie>(movieTitle, Movie))`. Take a look at [Insert Elements into map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/insert/)

Comment: @DOOM: Given the C++11 tag, I would use std::map::emplace rather than insert: movies.emplace(title, movie)

Comment: @DOOM The doubt I have now is how to call the copy constructor of Movie. When I am calling Movie(s) I am calling the copy constructor which takes string data of the file and load the data into its corresponding element.

Comment: I was able to load movies into the map. But now I am facing issue in returning the Movie class object from the getMovies function.

Comment: `return & it->second;` Is it what you want ?

Comment: const Movie* Movies::getMovie(string mc) const {

cout<<"Inside get Movies"<<endl;
Movie* tempObject=nullptr;
cout<<"Before find"<<endl;
map<string, Movie>::const_iterator it = movies.find(mc);
cout<<"After find"<<endl;
//*tempObject = it->second;
cout<<*tempObject;
cout<<"before return"<<endl;
return &it->second;}  IN this after the cout<<"After find" I am getting segmentation fault(core dumped). Please help